# if statement comparing multiple varaibles to 1 string

Tags: python, python-3.x

so no matter what I try with these if staments

```
if (x,y,z == "no no yes"):
    print ("REBEL ROBOT DETECTED, DESTROY IMMEDIATELY")
if (x,y,z ==  "no yes no"):
    print ("PERFECT SOLDOER DETECTED, REPORT TO US ARMY")
if (x,y,z == "yes no no"):
    print ("LONER ROBOT DETECTED, DESTROY IMMEDIATELY")
if (x,y,z == "no yes yes"):
    print ("THIS ROBOT HURTS HUMANS")
if (x,y,z == "yes yes no"):
    print ("This robot is self destructive")
if (x,y,z == "yes no yes"):
    print ("This robot disobeys orders")
if (x,y,z  == "no no no"):
    print ("YOU HAVE A PHYCOPATH ROBOT, DESTROY AT ALL COSTS")
```

it just prints all the strings, can someone help me with this

Comment: `if x == y == z == "literal"` may be what you're searching for -- this uses comparison operator chaining (a feature in python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x, y, z == "no no yes"` evaluates to a tuple of three values: `x`, `y`, and a Boolean (true/false) value indicating whether `z` is equal to `"no no yes"`. This being a tuple of non-zero length, it is truthy and so all `if` conditions pass.

Instead, write `(x, y, z) == ("no", "no", "yes")` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
(x,y,z == "no no yes")
```

This does not do what you expect it to do. First of all, you cannot compare multiple variables at the same time against a single string. You would need to split this up into separate checks.

But why does your code print all strings? This might be a bit surprising if you’re new to Python: The comma in Python separates tuple elements, so `x, y, z` would be a tuple with three elements, `x`, `y`, and `z`. A tuple would never be equal to a string, so why are all your check successful?

The reason is that the `==` operator binds stronger than the comma. So what you’re actually writing is something like this: `(x, y, (z == "no no yes"))`. So you compare `z` (and only `z`) against the string and put the result inside the tuple as the third value. `x` and `y` are taken as they are as the first and second element of the tuple.

And non-empty tuples happen to evaluate to `True` in Python. So the following will always work:

```
if (x, y, False):
    print('Works')
```

---

As mentioned above, to fix your code, you will have to check each variable against each value separately:

```
if x == "no no yes" or y == "no no yes" or z == "no no yes":
    print ("REBEL ROBOT DETECTED, DESTROY IMMEDIATELY")
```

Since you are checking for equality, you can also use the `in` operator here with the logic reversed:

```
if "no no yes" in (x, y, z):
    print ("REBEL ROBOT DETECTED, DESTROY IMMEDIATELY")
```

You can learn more about this (just in the other direction) from the following question: [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/216074)

---

And as I just realized from [kindall’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354549), you probably want to split up those strings into separate strings which you check against each variable separately:

```
if x == "no" and y == "no" and z == "yes":
    print ("REBEL ROBOT DETECTED, DESTROY IMMEDIATELY")
```